# Database performance - Primary Key vs UniqueIdentifier

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, angular7

I'm adding a new table in a database which could grow up to having millions of records. 
The table got two columns,

[image]

```
TicketId - PrimaryKey, Auto increment id 
RefNo - GUID, UniqueIdentifier
```

The purpose of RefNo is to extract the the record details and show on the UI. I don't wanna show the Primary key in the UI.

This is what the user will see on the URL when extracting the ticket details (id is the RefNo)

[image]

On the WebAPI project I'm passing the RefNo to the database (Entity Framework) and extract the record. All work fine at the moment.

My question is, when the table contains millions of data, will querying the database with GUID (RefNo) instead of the primary key affect the database performance?

Which one would be the faster and do I have any other options?

Comment: if you have the right index(es), querying millions of rows is very fast

Comment: Well, an `integer` needs just 4 byte whereas a `uniqueidentifier` needs 16 bytes. So an index of the same size can store 4 times as many `integer` keys than `uniqueidentifier` keys. There could be edge cases where this makes the difference of the index completely fitting in memory or not, with the latter causing more disk i/o. But in "every day situations" I think that's neglectable.

Comment: As Mitch said, appropriately indexed, it's not a problem but you really need to make sure the index is appropriate, and likely that means not just on the RefNo.

Comment: You also don't have to use a GUID to obscure this. There are plenty of ways that you could do that with a bigint, and it'd work much better.

Comment: BIGINT is fast as the hell and GUID is a real performance killer, believe me. Don't use the GUID as much as you can.

Comment: If you haven't index on GUID column, the queries will work slow. Just create a unique index on GUID and you won't see any difference between querying by ID or GUID.

Comment: @XAMT Do you have any more arguments other than 'believe me' ?

Answer (score -1):

There are many good comment on your query.  Since I'm new, limited to `add a comment` hence posting answer.

If there is designated DBA in your/client's team that takes care of maintenance of database indies than Int vs uniqueidentifier will not any difference.

Performance will be almost `equal`  Here is further details with example [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5105/sql-server-performance-comparison-int-versus-guid/)